# PHP PDO - Check whether a value exists within a column if another value is present in another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have the following PHP code

```
$queryTableProfileUpdate = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT business_profile_id, business_owner_id FROM TABLE_PROFILES WHERE business_profile_id = $businessOwnerID AND business_profile_id = ?");
$queryTableProfileUpdate->bindValue( 1, $businessProfileID);
$queryTableProfileUpdate->execute();
$resultTableProfileUpdate = $queryTableProfileUpdate->fetch();

if(($queryTableProfileUpdate->rowCount()) == 1) {
    echo 'Busines Profile Exists';
}
else {
    echo 'Business profile does NOT exist';
}
```

And this is my SQL table

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID        | business_profile_id        | business_owner_id              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 01        | 1234567                    | abcdefghi                      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02        | 2345678                    | abcdefghi                      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 03        | 3456789                    | abcdefghi                      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 04        | 1234589                    | xyzuvwxyz                      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In my above table `business_profile_id` is unique while `business_owner_id` is **not** unique.

In my conditional statement I want to check whether `business_profile_id` exists if `business_owner_id` is present.

If say I have `business_owner_id` **abcdefghi** and  `business_profile_id` **2345678** - I want the conditional statement to tell me that the record exists within **abcdefghi**.

Or else if say I have `business_owner_id` **xyzuvwxyz** and  `business_profile_id` **2345678** - I want the conditional statement to tell me that the record does **not** exists within **abcdefghi**.

I get no error logs just the conditional statement remains the same.

Comment: You answered your own question. The constraint is `business_profile_id` paired with `business_owner_id`. Make a compound unique key out of the two. Try to insert. If the insert fails with exception - it exists, otherwise it doesn't. Do not perform unique checks in PHP. That's the recipe to break your data integrity.

Comment: I'm confused by your "Or else if". There appears to be a business_profile_id 2345678 in xyzuvwxyz and you want the conditional to respond that the record does NOT exist in abcdefghi?

Comment: @michaelp I want to see if the business_profile_id  corresponds to business_owner_id

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your query:

```
    SELECT business_profile_id, business_owner_id FROM TABLE_PROFILES 
WHERE business_profile_id = $businessOwnerID AND business_profile_id = ?
```

should be:

```
    SELECT business_profile_id, business_owner_id FROM TABLE_PROFILES 
WHERE business_owner_id = $businessOwnerID AND business_profile_id = ?
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but even if the profile id exists and does not belong to the owner it still tells me it exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and seemed to work:

```
########## GET PROFILE DETAILS FROM MYSQL ##########
$queryBusinessID = $dbh->prepare("SELECT business_profile_id FROM TABLE_PROFILES WHERE business_owner_id = $businessOwnerIDSession");
$queryBusinessID->execute();

while ($resultBusinessID = $queryBusinessID->fetch()) {
    $businessProfileID = $resultBusinessID['business_profile_id'];
    ########## FORM DECISION ##########
    if($businessProfileID == $businessProfileIDUrl) {
        echo $businessProfileIDUrl .' - Profile exist <br/>'; 
    } else {
        echo $businessProfileIDUrl .' - Profile does not exist <br/>'; 
    }

}
```

I know that there are other optimal solutions. I'm open to new ideas.

Comment: and where is `$businessProfileIDUrl` from, your question is very hard to understand